# ajax deferred chaining call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a bit confused I am using the result of `callone()` to modify a global object(I'm not sure of a better way to do this) trying to accomplish this with deferred. By the time time I calltwo() the global object should be modified with the new data

```
var obj = {};

var id = obj.id;
//global object 
    $.when(callone(obj)).then(calltwo(id),function(data)
    {

    });
```

### - Ajax function :1

```
function callone(requiredData)
{
 var d = new $.Deferred();
 var ajaxCall1 =   $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: 'AB/',
            data: requiredData, 
            success: function(data) {

               //return data to the callee?

                d.resolve(p_obj);
                //set ID on the object
                obj.id = data.id;
                return obj;

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            },
            always: function(data)  {  }
        });

}

function calltwo(id from callback one)
{



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've included a much simpler implementation below.

`callone()` must return a deferred or promise for you to wait on it or chain other operations to it and you can just use the promise that `$.ajax()` already returns rather than creating your own.

Further, there is no reason to use `$.when()` here because it really only adds value when you're trying to wait on multiple promises running in parallel which isn't your case at all.  So, you can just use the `.then()` handler on the individual promises you already have.

In addition, you really don't want to use globals when processing async operations.  You can chain the promises and pass the data right through the promises.

Here's what `callone()` should look like:

```
function callone(requiredData) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'AB/',
        data: requiredData
    });
}

function calltwo(...) {
    // similar to callone
    // returns promise from $.ajax()
}

callone(...).then(function(data) {
    // when callone is done, use the id from its result
    // and pass that to calltwo
    return calltwo(data.id);
}).then(function(data) {
    // process result from calltwo here
}, function(err) {
    // ajax error here
});
```

Notice that this code isn't creating any new Deferred objects.  It's just using the promise that is already returned from `$.ajax()`.  Note also that it isn't use `success:` or `error:` handlers either because those also come through the promises.

Also, note that return a promise from within a `.then()` handler automatically  chains it into the previous promise so the previous promise won't be resolved until the newly returned promise is also resolved.  This allows you to keep the chain going.

Also, note that returning data from an async callback function does not return data back to the caller of the original function so your attempt to return something from the `success:` handler was not accomplishing anything.  Instead, use promises and return data through the promises as they are specifically designed to get async data back to the `.then()` handlers.

Comment: im a bit confused so `$.ajax` returns a promise?

Comment: @Undermine2k - yes it does.  From the [jQuery `$.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): **The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise**.  You can use their `.then()` handler to see the success or failure of the ajax operation and you can chain them with other promise-based async operations.  This is a most excellent feature that should be taken advantage of rather than manually creating new promises.

Comment: ok so remove all the success handlers on the ajax function and put then inside the then function?

Comment: @Undermine2k - yes.  I think it makes a lot clearer code to not mix regular  success callbacks with promises and promise callbacks.  If you're using promises, just use promises - the code stays a lot cleaner (IMO).